# How do I apply the textbox SelectionBrush property to a listbox item?

Tags: c#, wpf

As opposed to using the default highlight brush, I want the color of a selected list box item to be the same as the color of selected text in a text box. I'm thinking it would be a x:Reference, but what if I need to do this at the control template triggers level inside a style element?

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Border Name="Border" Padding="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The setter value for the is selected trigger is what I want to make equal to the text selection brush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you`re almost there. Judging by [TextBoxBase.SelectionOpacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.selectionopacity.aspx)  property, default `Opacity` for selection brush is 0.4 so we have to emulate that:

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightColorKey}}" 
                             Opacity="0.4" />
        </Setter.Value>                                
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

I tested it and it looks exactly like selected text background in `TextBox`.

Comment: That works. Can the Opacity be made dynamic too? My actual goal is to grab both properties from TextBoxBase...

Comment: Well, color is not exactly from `TextBox`, it\`s just a resource that `TextBox` is using as default color internally. And opacity is not even a resource, just a numeric value set internally by default, so I don\`t think there\`s an easy way to just reference it.